# $Var[XY]$ proof for independent $X$ and $Y$

Tags: statistics

$\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}$I'm trying to prove that $\Var[XY]=\Var[X]Var[Y]+\E[X]^2 \Var[Y]+\E[Y]^2 \Var[X]$. I've tried using both $\Var[XY]=\E[(XY-\E[XY])^2]$ and $\Var[XY]=\E[X^2Y^2]-\E[XY]^2$ but am not getting anywhere. I know that I can use $\E[XY]=\E[X]\E[Y]$ and $\Var[X+Y]=\Var[X]+\Var[Y]$. Could use some help.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{var}{\operatorname{Var}}$
\begin{align}E[X^2Y^2]-E[XY]^2&=E[X^2]E[Y^2]-E[X]^2E[Y]^2=\\&=(\var[X]+E[X]^2)(\var[Y]+E[Y]^2)-E[X]^2E[Y]^2=\\&=\var[X]\var[Y]+\var[X]E[Y]^2+\var[Y]E[X]^2\end{align}

The first passage is justified by the fact that $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are independent as well.

Comment: Thanks. Didn’t think of using E[X^2]=Var[X]+E[X]^2. That’s pretty clever!

Comment: It's just a matter of "going from here to there".